# Advantages of numpy column_stack

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a large amount of data relating to the redshifts and magnitudes of galaxies (29000 of them), which I'll be plotting against each other and performing statistics upon. At the moment, they're in separate lists, so that I can produce graphs such as [image] which I just threw together as an illustrative example.

I'll eventually need things like regressions and linear fits. Given that there are a lot of points on the graphs (something like 11000), would there be any advantage to stacking the columns into an array with numpy.column_stack?

Comment: It depends: if you are going to run a script made using numpy, and in the script you will be needing all the points, the of course.

Comment: Are the lists all the same length?  There is a numpy function called `column_stack`, but it's just version of its `concatenate` - which can join arrays of matching size into an array of higher dimensionality.